# Android Studio throwing error when trying to access static variable

Tags: java, android, static

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hangman_guess);
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lives);
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < WordHandler.lives; i++) // Error on this line
        s += new String(Character.toChars(0x2764));
    t.setText(s);
}
```

When I run this code, I get a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` on the commented line, which is caused by a `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException` at the following line:

`public static String word = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.default_word);`

The variable `WordHandler.lives` is defined as `public static int lives = 5;`
  Why is this exception being thrown?  Am I not allowed to call `Resources.getSystem()`?

Comment: You're allowed to call `Resources.getSystem()`, but your app's resources aren't going to be found in the system `Resources`. You need to call `getResources()` on a `Context` to get your app's `Resources`, and get the `String` from that.

Comment: @MikeM. How would I do that?

Comment: Well, you can directly call `getResources()` in your `Activity`, since it's a `Context`.

Comment: The class WordHandler is not an activity so that method doesn't exist.

Comment: Then you'll have to either get your resources in a `Context`/`Activity` and pass them to `WordHandler`, or pass a `Context` to `WordHandler`, and let it do its own thing.

Comment: @MikeM. Would I do this by creating a static Context object in an Activity and accessing it from WordHandler, or am I messing this up?

Comment: No, don't do that. Static `Context` fields are a bad thing. Assuming `WordHandler` is just a bunch of `static` utility methods and fields, you can create a `static init(Context context) {...}` method, for example, get your resources in that, and call that method with the `Activity` as the argument before you try to use `WordHandler`

Comment: @MikeM. Ok.  Thanks.  And while I have you what is the method to access strings.xml

Comment: It's the same method - `getString(R.string.whatever)` - but you just need to call it on your own `Resources`. E.g., in that `init()` method - `word = context.getResources().getString(R.string.default_word);`.